# Setting pages for posts

Tags: php, json

This is my json rest api function. When called, it returns 24 posts, but there are much more in total. How can I page the response so I can change pages with something like `?page=2` to be added to curl request route.

```
public function posts(){
     $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 24,         
    'offset'           => 0,
    'meta_key'         => $meta_key,
    'orderby'          => $orderby,
    'order'            => 'DESC',       
    'post_type'        => 'videos',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );

    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ($posts_array as $rate_posts){
        $get_author_id = $rate_posts->post_author;
        $author_data = get_userdata( $get_author_id );
        $city = get_the_author_meta( 'city', $author_data->ID );
        $phone = get_the_author_meta( 'phone', $author_data->ID );

        $data['User_id']=$get_author_id;
        $data['Username']=$author_data->user_nicename;
        $data['City']=$city;
        $data['Phone']=$phone;
        $data['Post_id'] =$rate_posts->ID;
   }
   return $data;
```

Comment: Did you try the pagination parameters as described in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) ?

Comment: I did try but i am not sure how to properly add a query with my $data variable.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions is to add a $page entering value to the function and in the curl route that represents the page number to end up with a route like this

curl -i websitename/wp-json/posts/page_number

where $page is page_number

```
    public function posts($page){
         $args = array(
        'author'   => $id,         
        'posts_per_page'   => 24,         
        'offset'           => 0,
        'meta_key'         => $meta_key,
        'orderby'          => $orderby,
        'order'            => 'DESC', 
        'paged'           => $page,
        'post_type'        => 'videos',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
         'suppress_filters' => true );
```